# Selenium Python chose and select between two similar icons

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want python selenium to press the icon Politics but on the International part, I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//class[contains(., 'Politics')][1]").click()` where [1] should place it on the International part but is not working. Can anybody help me please. Below is the HTML code I'm working with.

```
<li class="level-1 National "> 
      <li class="level-2 collapse">
           <span class="text"><span class="news-icon politics" title="Politics"></span>politics</span>
        <ul style="display:none">
                <li class="collapse">

<li class="level-1 International "> 
        <li class="level-2 collapse">
                 <span class="text"><span title="Politics" class="news-icon politics"></span>politics</span>
        <ul style="display:none">
             <li class="collapse">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use xpath I would recommend not to use index like **[1]**.

So your xpath could look like:

> "//li[contains(@class, 'International')]//*[contains(@title,'Politics')]"

A little bit more larger than CSS

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly!! It works perfectly!!I

Answer (score 0):

I would instead write a *CSS selector* - much more concise:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.International span.politics")
```

Comment: @Johnny007 glad to help. Well, seriously, compare the expressions - which is simpler and less cryptic? :)